# Android app 101: how do I sync web contents to the app? just starting building applications

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to build my own android application, and I was wondering if someone can direct me or help me find a tutorial on what to do to get contents between the two. I've been teaching myself php and web building and now I'm trying to build an android app.

But I have no idea as to how to sync the two pieces together? Say if I wanted to update some contents on my php page, how would it be updated to my android app? I'm also beginner at java, but I do have ambition to learning these things.

Thank you in advance fellow members.

ps I've been messing around with eclipse and the android platform.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you specify your question more? Are you thinking about how to update your application once some web page has changed? Do you want to have your Android app displaying web content? Or are you just curious how to update Android applications in general as users of web apps by nature use always the newest version?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify myself. Not just update my application, but instead update the contents. Say for example: Groupon or Living Social, they have daily deals. How would these contents be integrated? Does groupon only work on their website content and then the application will have the content updated? Or does groupon have to go into their java code to update the contents on the application? Let me know if this clarifies my question. Thank you for responding

Comment: rhololkeolke gives you a good direction. Rate his answer if it helps and create a new question as soon as you find more specific questions during your research. Good luck!

Comment: ^^ thank you. I can't rate it. But yeah he definitely did. This site is still new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you wanted to write it from scratch or find some sort of library.  I've also just started android development and I stumbled across a project called openmobster.
http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/
It's a library for integrating mobile applications with web based services.  They have tutorials and documentation in the wiki section.  For example: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp

If you were interested in writing something from scratch you should be able to browse the source to see some of the things they are doing.

Comment: interesting, I'll look more into it.